# Nested Classes and Inheritance

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, void

I'm trying to use the function that I have inside my base class "SHAPE" with the derived class "RECTANGLE" to create a bigger rectangle in my class "BIGRECTANGLE". I want to do have my sides transformation inside the class and not in the main, What should I do? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Base class Shape
class Shape
{
public:

    void ResizeW(int w)
    {
        width = w;
    }
    void ResizeH(int h)
    {
        height = h;
    }
protected:

    int width;
    int height;
};

// Primitive Shape

class Rectangle: public Shape
{
public:

    int width = 2;
    int height = 1;
    int getArea()
    {
        return (width * height);
    }
};

// Derived class

class BIGRectangle: public Rectangle
{
public:

    int area;
    Rectangle.ResizeW(8);
    Rectangle.ResizeH(4);
    area = Rectangle.getArea();
};

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

These are the errors that I have:
- 45:14: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token
- 46:14: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token
- 47:5: error: 'area' does not name a type

Comment: Put that stuff in a constructor or whatever... Do you know what constructors are? You're not using them.

Comment: @LogicStuff can you help me to figure out?

Comment: Here's a link to a [tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) on constructors. And another link on [inheritance](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/inheritance/intro/). Read them; Google is your friend.

Comment: Also, your `main()` function is doing nothing. Either get rid of it, or do something with it relevant to demonstrating your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a time and a place for everything. In

```
class BIGRectangle: public Rectangle
{
public:

    int area;
    Rectangle.ResizeW(8);
    Rectangle.ResizeH(4);
    area = Rectangle.getArea();
};
```

the best place to initialize class members in is [Member Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) of the constructor. For example:

```
class BIGRectangle: public Rectangle
{
public:

    int area;

    BIGRectangle():Rectangle(8, 4), area(getArea())
    {
    }
};
```

This says, build me a `BIGRectangle` that is made of a `Rectangle` that is 8 by 4 and stores the `Rectangle`'s computed `area`.

But that requires `Rectangle` to have a constructor that requires height and width.

```
class Rectangle: public Shape
{
public:

    // no need for these because they hide the width and height of Shape
    // int width = 2;
    // int height = 1;
    Rectangle(int width, int height): Shape(width, height)
    {

    }
    int getArea()
    {
        return (width * height);
    }
};
```

That addition builds a `Rectangle` that uses `Shape`'s `width` and `height` rather than its own. When given two names in the same place, the compiler will pick the one declared inner most and hide the outer-most, and this leads to confusion and accidents. `Rectangle` sees its `width` and `height` and needs help to see those defined in `Shape`. `Shape` has no clue that `Rectangle` even exists because `Rectangle` was defined after `Shape`. As a result `Shape` only sees its `width` and `height`.

This leads to some real nasty juju when you call `getArea`. The current version sets `Shape`'s `width` and `height` and uses `Rectangle`'s `width` and `height` to compute the area. Not what you want to happen.

And that requires Shape to have a constructor that takes width and height

```
class Shape
{
public:
    Shape(int inwidth,
          int inheight): width(inwidth), height(inheight)
    {

    }
    void ResizeW(int w)
    {
        width = w;
    }
    void ResizeH(int h)
    {
        height = h;
    }
protected:

    int width;
    int height;
};
```

Note how the parameter is `inwidth`, not `width`. This isn't strictly necessary, but it's bad form to use the same name twice in the same place or close proximity for the same reasons as above: The same name in the same place at the same time is bad.

But this asks the question of what happens when you have `Circle` which is a `Shape`. Circles have no width or height, so you may want to rethink `Shape`.

Comment: This is Perfect Thanks!

Comment: Not quite perfect. The hierarchy falls down as soon as you have non-rectangular shapes. Every layer back to the root in an object hierarchy should know less than the previous because it has to be more abstract. Shape knows just as much as Rectangle, and this prevents Shape from also representing a circle, triangle, or anything else that isn't rectangular. Shape should be really, really, *really* dumb. It shouldn't know anything.